# Is there a reason why one's calfs would ache on a Turbo or Spinner, but not when riding on the road?

Tags: health, technique, muscle-pain

I'm not on my own on this one as at least two other people in my Spinning class suffer the same:  when Spinning or on the Turbo Trainer, I can feel pressure on my calf muscles after a bit of time (usually less than 45 minutes).  But I can ride on the road for up to 3 hours without feeling any pressure.

I think it's something to do with leg angles:  on the road, the bike changes angle slightly to best match the angle of the leg, but on a spinner or Turbo, it's fixed and so can't move.

Are there any proven reasons why calfs would ache on a static bike but not on the road?

Comment: Yes I get this too, I can ride outside all day but only for an hour or so on a trainer. Not so much aches but certainly tiredness. The trainer is so much more intense....I think you could be right about bike movement, but I also find ventilation/overheating becomes a problem, plus I think we can tend to underestimate the amount of "resting" we're able to do on the open road as opposed the the constant effort required on a turbo.

Comment: I'm guessing it's mostly the intensity, and the lack of variety.  The calves have a particular tendency toward "capsule syndrome" where the muscles swell and are "trapped" by the membrane around them.  This can become quite serious in some cases, requiring surgery to relieve the pressure.

Comment: Overheating is definitely a problem. I had my trainer in my unheated garage over the winter.  It could be 5 degrees in there, but by the time I was done a 40-60 minute ride, I was quite comfortable in regular cycling shorts and jersey.  Also I found that I would more often put the bike in a harder gear than I would on the road.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that on a trainer, you most likely don't stop pedaling.  On a regular road bike, there are almost always situations where you are going to stop pedaling, at least briefly.  Be it going around a sharp bend, going down a steep hill, or just because you're drafting off somebody and pedaling would mean that you run into their back wheel.

Comment: @DanielRHicks this health issue you mention (compartment syndrome) is very serious and never happens during physiological conditions, even under extreme exercise. Severe tissue damage with large swelling is required to close the blood vessels and start necrosis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartment_syndrome

Comment: @heltonbiker - Serious compartment syndrome can happen in cases of intense training.  It's been known to happen in football training camp, eg.  But well before it becomes serious (to the point where circulation is impaired, etc), it becomes uncomfortable -- the legs feel "inflated" and sort of cramped.

Comment: @DanielRHicks interesting, I didn't know that! (indeed, googling "exercise induced compartment syndrome" returns a lot of results, most of them related to the lower limbs).

Comment: @heltonbiker - Yeah, the lower legs are the most sensitive muscles with regard to this, because they are large muscles and are fairly tightly restrained by the membrane.  Muscles swell with exercise, especially when stressed beyond "normal", and that swelling is enough to make the lower legs feel "tight".  In the severe cases the muscles have generally been exercised to the point of exhausting their glycogen, then pushed further with something like squats.  I understand the pain is agonizing.

Comment: (Reflecting on this, a cyclist might set up a serious situation by cycling all day and then forcing himself to do a major climb at the end of the day.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks well I must assume it would still be rare, since all my friends for decades have been cyclists, and there were all sorts of "go-all-the-way"-freaks among them. Never seen or heard anything even closely related to that... I guess you have to go REALLY beyond all limits to damage the muscles like that (I guess fatigue and hunger comes much faster...)

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly highly unlikely that a cyclist would experience the full-blown compartment syndrome.  In particular, the cycling motion does not cut off blood flow like squats do, and squats (or something similar) are usually the coup de grace.  But it's good to be aware of the danger.  ..... But my original point was that the lower legs have a propensity to swell and become compressed, much more than other muscles, and this contributes to the lower leg pain described by the OP.

Comment: Trainers/spinning != real world riding, that's one thing for sure.  I can spend all day on a real bike, but the trainer knocks me out in no time flat.  My wife is the opposite.  She can spin fast for an hour, but on the road she gets dropped like she's standing still...

Answer (score 5):

There are likely a few different reasons, but my primary suspicion would be fit. Presumably your road bike is set up to fit your body geometry and angles, where the spin bike is not. Small differences in how a bike is set up can have a big impact on how your body feels while riding.

My n=1 example, when doing higher intensity efforts on the road, I would get high calf cramps after about an hour. When I had a Retul fit done for my time trial bike, the fitter told me that because my feet were somewhat duckfooted, I needed to move to speedplay pedals with longer spindles to allow my heels to drift inward more than my old pedals. Solved my calf cramp problems.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't found any of these answers satisfactory. I use my road bike on my trainer, so fit can't be an issue. I don't train hard on the trainer, always 130bmp heart rate. The only difference is I spend more time upright on the trainer than on the road.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This doesn't really answer the question, though.  You state that the existing answers aren't correct, but don't say what the correct answer _is_.  Please don't post comments as answers; you might want to take the [tour].

Comment: Are you saying that you believe the reason that it affects different muscles differently is the upright position? If so, it would be helpful to spell that out more clearly in your answer to avoid future downvotes.

Answer (score -4):

It could be the way how you set up your spinner.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider expanding your answer to explain how to correctly set up a spinner. I have also removed your link as it did not add any value to your answer. Please review our [behavior policy](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) which includes self-promotion rules before posting further links.